# Сгенерировать строку на основе ключа

Tags: php

Необходимо сгенерировать строку из ключа, но нужно, чтобы эта строка имела по возможности как можно больше разных букв английского алфавита в верхнем и нижнем регистре (+ числа)

Последнее уточнение было потому, что классические функции хеширования дают какое-то ограниченное количество букв

Comment: Все основные алгоритмы хеширования дают не буквы, а байты

Comment: А уже байты можно преобразовать во что угодно, например в base64 с буквами и цифрами